# Get data already sent from handheld to wear

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have sent data from mobile to wear as

```
    private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "/image";
    private static final String IMAGE_TITLE = "imageTitle";
    private static final String IMAGE_TO_SEND = "image";


    PutDataMapRequest putDataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create(IMAGE_PATH);
    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putString(IMAGE_TITLE, "hi this handheld");
    PutDataRequest putDataRequest = putDataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();
    putDataRequest.setUrgent();
    Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleApiClient, putDataRequest).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
            if (dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

On wear side I want to first check if data has been already sent or not. If data has been sent already then I want to use that data otherwise I want to request data for mobile:

I have done it but it always fails. My code is as follow:

```
 Wearable.NodeApi.getLocalNode(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull NodeApi.GetLocalNodeResult getLocalNodeResult) {
                Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                        .scheme(PutDataRequest.WEAR_URI_SCHEME)
                        .path(IMAGE_PATH)
                        .authority(getLocalNodeResult.getNode().getId())
                        .build();

                Wearable.DataApi.getDataItem(googleApiClient, uri).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
                        if (dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess() && dataItemResult.getDataItem() != null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResult: success result");
                            DataMap dataMap = DataMap.fromByteArray(dataItemResult.getDataItem().getData());

                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. I was checking data by getting **local nodes id** ,so that it was providing null data.Local Node id i-e id of my watch, Node Id must be id of node which has sent data using Data Layer Api. In my case at first my handheld sends data through the [Data Layer Api](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) and my watch checks data exist or not.If data found gets data otherwise send request to Handheld.

```
Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes) {
                    for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                        connectedNode = node;
                    }

                    Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                            .scheme(PutDataRequest.WEAR_URI_SCHEME)
                            .path(IMAGE_PATH)
                            .authority(connectedNode.getId()) //id which has sent data
                            .build();

                    Wearable.DataApi.getDataItem(googleApiClient, uri).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
                            if (dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess() && dataItemResult.getDataItem() != null) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: successfully got previous data");
                            } else {
                                makeRequestToSendData();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: failed to got previous data");//request handheld to get data using **Message API**
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

We have to change **getLocalNode** to **getConnectedNodes** .

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, is the node id non null ?

Does it fail at the getDataItem result callback ?

To get the DataMap from the DataItemResult, use this code :

```
DataItem dataItem = dataItemResult.getDataItem();
if (dataItem != null) {
       DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(dataItem).getDataMap();

}
```

Comment: id of node is not null. it fails at the getDataItem result callback.dataItem is always null.

Comment: @Kapouter I didn't found any difference between your answer and post.Code are same as asked from the blogspot link given in answer.

Comment: Do you have the same package names between your mobile and wear modules ? Is the GoogleApiClient connected correctly ?

Comment: @Kapouter looks he got the answer